# Faking instance variables in Objective-C categories with Associative References - Error "Use of undeclared identifier 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to create "fake" instance variables in categories by using `objc_setAssociatedObject`as described in this [post](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/).

However, I get the following error using ARC in iOS 6.1: `Use of undeclared identifier 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` for the following code snippet:

```
- (void)setStyleName:(NSString *)styleName
{
   objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kDHStyleKey, styleName,
   OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

Has anything changed for iOS 6.1?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I did not import: `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 1):

You must import `#import <objc/runtime.h>`in order to use associated objects provided by objc-runtime so as to be able to fake instance variables or properties in a category.

Also i would like to point out that using instance varaibles in category gives compile time warning saying that iVars are not allowed in a category but using property in a category doesn't warn you at compile time if you use @dynamic for it. Instead it will lead you to a crash at runtime when you will try to set that property in a class.